# ASP.NET SqlBulkCopy does not insert all records on server

Tags: asp.net, sql, .net, database, sqlbulkcopy

I don't have any idea why SqlBulkCopy does not insert all of the records from the reader. Code:

```
using (OleDbDataReader dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
       using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ss, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock, null))
       {
            bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
            bulkCopy.BatchSize = 500;
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
            try
            {
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr1);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.LogSystemLog(ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }

       }

       GC.Collect();
       dr1.Close();
   }
```

I want to bulkCopy about 300k records. It works when I'm running this from localhost to the same database, but when I run this from the server - it always inserts ~7k records... and no error, or exception. On the server 4GB free RAM are available.  On localhost ~ 1,5GB.

I have no idea why it's working properly on localhost, but on the server it is not.

Comment: SqlBulkCopy is not buggy. Maybe your logging is broken or you missed the log message. Remove the catch and let the error bubble up. Don't use boolean return values to propagate errors. That leads to not noticing them easily.; Or, your reader returned less rows than you think it should.

Comment: But why the same code works proper when I'm debugging(on localhost) ?

Comment: Maybe the data is different or a batch is timing out or there's a network blip. We'll never find out if you don't make 100% sure that you get errors (should there be any, which is likely). Nobody can help you till you do. You will not receive useful answers without an error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, solved by adding the following to my connection string.

*IMEX=1*

**Example:**

string **connectionString** = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"                                    + "Data Source=" + Server.MapPath(rutacom) + ";"                                     + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES; IMEX=1'";

In my localhost was working perfectly, but not on server.

Try it :)

**Notes:**

"HDR=Yes;" indicates that the first row contains columnnames, not data. "HDR=No;" indicates the opposite.

To always use IMEX=1 is a safer way to retrieve data for mixed data columns. Consider the scenario that one Excel file might work fine cause that file's data causes the driver to guess one data type while another file, containing other data, causes the driver to guess another data type. This can cause your app to crash.